# How to save all entities in nifi ui into template using rest api?

Tags: hortonworks-data-platform, apache-nifi

i having lot of process groups and processors in Nifi UI-0.6.1.Now i need to save all entities as templates using rest api.

In generally snippet ID is needed for create template.

If i have tried snippet ID creation for single process group in below json Contents.

```
  {
    "revision": {
        "version": 109
    },
     "snippet": {
        "parentGroupId": "root",
       "processGroups":["d3ea576e-d474-4edd-8b11-43071bcaf252"]

    }
}
```

i could be able created the snippet ID and Template for single process group.

**But i need to all entities(ProcessGroups,Processors) in UI to be save as template.**

How to create snippetID for all entities in UI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create a template from the root canvas with nothing selected, it will include everything in the template. You could open the developer tools in your browser to see what request your browser makes to the NiFi API when you do this.

Comment: Bryan,i just go through developer tools,it will pass the all id's of entities into json content.it will create snippetID by process all id's.How to create snippetID for entire UI?

Comment: Bryan,i have use rest api for collect all processors and process groups and then pass this into snippet creation.Now i can able to create template for entire ui. Is this correct way?